# Is it possible to have a child have a higher z index than its parent

Tags: html, css, less

Code Extract:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="other">

</div>
```

What i want to do is have the other class render above parent but below child is this possible?

Comment: Yes https://jsfiddle.net/oab4z0du/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  opacity: .9;
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.other {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  opacity: .9;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
</div>

<div class="other"></div>
```